# Hammerspoon hs.application:kill() not callable

Tags: lua, hammerspoon

Trying to get Hammerspoon to quit (kill) the Music app in OS X whenever it opens. (This application has been installed by Apple in such a way as to make it very difficult to alter and it launches whenever a bluetooth device is connected. Annoying bloatware, basically.) So, I cribbed this from the Hammerspoon "Getting started" page https://www.hammerspoon.org/go/...

```
function applicationWatcher(appName, eventType, appObject)
  if (eventType == hs.application.watcher.launched) then
    if (appName == "Music") then
      hs.application:kill()
    end
  end
end
appWatcher = hs.application.watcher.new(applicationWatcher)
appWatcher:start()
```

This correctly responds to the Music app being launched, but it errors out like so... `ERROR: LuaSkin: hs.application.watcher callback: /Users/seancamden/.hammerspoon/init.lua:142: method 'kill' is not callable (a nil value)`

How I can make this method callable? Or, what is the right way to do this?

https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.application.watcher.html
https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.application.html#kill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is pretty much right, there is only one mistake. You used the global module `hs.application` and tried to call an object method `:kill()` from it. You would have to instantiate a new object first to be able to call it's `kill` method. For example: `hs.application.get(appName):kill()`.

However, the watcher already provides you with the application object that called the function as `appObject`. So `appObject:kill()` is what you are looking for.

```lua
function applicationWatcher(appName, eventType, appObject)
  if (eventType == hs.application.watcher.launched) then
    if (appName == "Music") then
      appObject:kill()
    end
  end
end

appWatcher = hs.application.watcher.new(applicationWatcher)
appWatcher:start()
```

Tested here on MacOS BigSur